# Get a Tiny URL's real URL and store as PHP variable

Tags: php, url, youtube

I want to get the video ID of a Youtube URL, but often the URL is condensed into a Tiny URL when being shared.

For example, I have a script that gets the Youtube video's thumbnail based on its video ID =

```
<?php $vlog = "OeqlkEymQ94"; ?>
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?=$vlog;?>/0.jpg" alt="" />
```

This is easy to get when the URL I'm extracting it from is

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeqlkEymQ94
```

but sometimes the URL is a tiny URL so I have to figure out how to return the real URL so I can use it.

```
http://tinyurl.com/kmx9zt6
```

Is it possible to retreive the real URL of a URL through PHP?

Comment: You could use CURL with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION = TRUE` and then parse the response header.

Comment: @Marcel, setting it to true would make cURL follow that redirection automatically, and only deliver the end result – it should be false instead, so that you get the result of the first request, that will contain the location header in the response …

Comment: True, but one could debate whether that is the wanted result. To me, you would want to follow all redirects, just like the browser would. Though I see your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/get_headers) or [`cURL`](http://php.net/curl) to grab the `Location` header:

```
function getFullURL($url) {
    $headers = get_headers($url);
    $headers = array_reverse($headers);
    foreach($headers as $header) {
        if (strpos($header, 'Location: ') === FALSE) {
            $url = str_replace('Location: ', '', $header);
            break;
        }
    }    
    return $url;
}
```

Usage:

```
echo getFullURL('http://tinyurl.com/kmx9zt6');
```

<sup>Note: It's a slightly modified version of the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/abailiss/1196916).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I used a much simpler function because my Tiny URL's were always going to resolve to Youtube, and the headers were almost always the same :

```
function getFullURL($url) {
    $headers = get_headers($url);
    $url = $headers[4]; //This is the location part of the array
    $url = str_replace('Location: ', '', $url);
    $url = str_replace('location: ', '', $url);  //in my case the location was lowercase, but it can't hurt to have both
    return $url;
}
```

usage -

```
echo getFullURL('http://tinyurl.com/kmx9zt6');
```